# SQL Compact Edition Batch Update

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-6

I am currently using Entity Framework and need to update a multitude of entities on a regular basis.

What i need to do is add a journaling number, which is based on several different tables. Using SQL Server, i can use a stored procedure, with inner and outer joins, GROUP BY and ROW_NUMBER, that does the heavy lifting for me and is also very efficient.

See the procedure code as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateNumber]
    @RefId int
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE TableWithNumber 
    SET Nmr = other.Nmr
    FROM (
        SELECT MIN(C.Nmr) as Nmr, Z_ID
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY D.TicksCreatedOn, D.Z_Id, D.B_ID) as Nmr, D.*
                FROM (
                    SELECT 
                            S.Id as S_ID,
                            Z.Id as Z_ID,
                            B.Id as B_ID,
                            S.TicksCreatedOn
                    FROM 
                            ChildTable as B
                            INNER JOIN TableWithNumber Z on Z.ChildTableRefA_Id = B.Id
                            INNER JOIN ParentTable S on Z.ParentTable_Id = S.Id
                    WHERE S.Ref_Id = @RefId
                UNION
                    SELECT 
                            S.Id as S_ID,
                            Z.Id as Z_ID,
                            B.Id as B_ID,
                            S.TicksCreatedOn
                    FROM 
                            ChildTable as B
                            INNER JOIN TableWithNumber Z on Z.ChildTableRefB_Id = B.Id
                            INNER JOIN ParentTable S on Z.ParentTable_Id = S.Id
                    WHERE S.Ref_Id = @RefId) as D
        ) as C
    GROUP BY C.Z_ID) as other
    WHERE other.Z_ID = Id AND Ref_Id = @RefId
END
```

Due stored procedures not being available in SQL Ce, and further restrictions on how you can use GROUP BY in sub selects, i now have to calculate the journaling number in code. I use SqlQuery on the Context to retrieve a minimum required data set, group it and then begin the update per entity.

```
SELECT ZID
FROM
    (SELECT S.Id as [SID], Z.Id as [ZID], B.Id as [BID], S.TicksCreatedOn
    FROM ChildTable AS B
        INNER JOIN TableWithNumber as Z on Z.ChildTableRefA_Id = B.Id
        INNER JOIN ParentTable as S on Z.ParentTable_Id = S.Id
    WHERE S.Ref_Id = @RefId
    UNION
    SELECT S.Id as [SID], Z.Id as [ZID], B.Id as [BID], S.TicksCreatedOn
    FROM ChildTable AS B
        INNER JOIN TableWithNumber as Z on Z.ChildTableRefB_Id = B.Id
        INNER JOIN ParentTable as S on Z.ParentTable_Id = S.Id
        WHERE S.Ref_Id = @RefId) AS D
ORDER BY TicksCreatedOn, ZID, BID


        var result = Database.SqlQuery<NumberUpdate>(QUERY, new SqlCeParameter("@RefId", 1)).ToList();
```

The code on the application looks somewhat like this

```
    var grouped = result
        .Select((x,y) => new NumberUpdate { ZID = x.ZID, Number = ++y })
        .GroupBy(x => x.ZID);

    foreach (var group in grouped)
    {
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE TableWithNumber SET Number = @Nr WHERE Id = @Id",
            new SqlCeParameter("@Nr", group.Min(x => x.Number)),
            new SqlCeParameter("@Id", group.Key));
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a faster or more efficient way to update a list of entities in SQL CE than calling ExecuteSqlCommand in a foreach loop?

Comment: The only improvement I could find is to prepare SqlCeCommand before the `foreach` loop and then within the loop only change values of existing parameters. But UPDATE is very limited within SQL CE.

Comment: If you need stored procedures and triggers in an embeddable database, consider [LocalDB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx).

Comment: LocalDB would have been GREAT and would have loved to use it. However, one crucial requirement of our application is, that it should be deployable copy/past and should not require an installation routine. Since LocalDB requires a setup on the client, it was unfortunatly not an option. Once again, i would have LOVED to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If your business logic allows you to update data in several tables "row by row" (not with a complex SQL command), you may try "table-direct" approach. It involves the following steps.

Create *SqlCeConnection* object with connection string pointing to your SDF file. Create *SqlCeCommand* object for this connection with command type *CommandType.TableDirect*. Create *SqlCeResultSet* with options *ResultSetOptions.Updatable* and *ResultSetOptions.Scrollable*.

Now you are able to update table rows using *Seek*, *Read* and *Update* methods. This approach possibly is the fastest way possible. But it requires to write much more code than traditional EF approach.